# Use C++17 in Qt Android

Tags: android, qt, c++17

Qt recommends to use Android NDK r10e, which uses GCC 4.9 that does not compile C++17 code. So is it still possible to write a Qt Android app in C++17?

Comment: Out of interest, does QT experience any side-effects if you choose to use a later version of the NDK?

Comment: @MichaelDodd The app fails to start if I use r16. The problem seems common according to the [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Android)

Comment: you have to use clang and a newer NDK. Which will generate binaries approx. 30% larger, and is currently unsupported by Qt. But some have reported it to work.

Comment: I am not sure but may be Android platform plugin that is bundled with the application when using the tool chain puts that limitation ..

Answer (score 0):

For C++17 support you need use NDK 17 or above.
You can use Qt 5.12.X that works fine for me with NDK 19.

NDK Download Page: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

PS: I tried use r20 but no success, then I'm using r19c.

I didn't tried with r18c but to get the r19c link replace the version part of url like the example. (link for MacOS)

Ex: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r20-darwin-x86_64.zip

Becomes: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-darwin-x86_64.zip

Source: 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support?hl=pt-br